# C - Split TCHAR

Tags: c, string, split, scanf, tchar

How can I split a `TCHAR` into other variables?
Example:

```
TCHAR comando[50], arg1[50], arg2[50];
Mensagem msg;
_tcscpy(msg.texto, TEXT("MOVE 10 12"));
```

So, `msg.texto` has the string "MOVE 10 12" and I want the variable `comando[50]` to be "MOVE", the variable `arg1` to be "10" and the variable `arg2` to be "12". How can I do that?
Sorry for some possible English mistakes.
Thanks in advance!

SOLVED:

```
TCHAR *pch;
    pch = _wcstok(msg.texto, " ");
        _tcscpy(comando, pch);
        pch = _wcstok(NULL, " ");
        _tcscpy(arg1, pch);
        pch = _wcstok(NULL, " ");
        _tcscpy(arg2, pch);
```

Comment: What is `TCHAR` in your system? A `char` for example?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [`TCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx), you could use [`strtok`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx), like in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char TCHAR;

int main ()
{
  TCHAR str[] ="MOVE 10 12";
  TCHAR * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In case it is a `wchar_t`, then you could use [`wcstok()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx):

> `wchar_t *wcstok( wchar_t *strToken, const wchar_t *strDelimit );`

Comment: As I recall, `TCHAR` may be either `char` or `wchar_t` -- more commonly the latter. `strtok` does not work on arrays of `wchar_t`. (I don't remember whether there's a corresponding function that operates on wide strings.)

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for justifying your downvote. Many people don't! Please see the comments under the question, where I asked the OP about it. He answered with this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842072.aspx). However, if you would like to propose how I could improve my answer, please let me know!

Comment: @gsmaras thanks for your help but that doesn't work.

Comment: @user3088049 same for `wcstok()`?

Comment: Did a litle adjustments and it's working, thank you!

Comment: @gsamaras I already put it in my answer and accept your answer as the right one

Answer (score 1):

To use the version agnostic, you should use `_tcstok`.